# Facebook Like Button Doesn't Fetch Proper, Title, Description, Image

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, facebook-like

I have set all my meta properties in the way I understand they should be. Currently when I 'like' the page it only posts the info index home page. The image is the last image written in the markup.

My page structure uses .htaccess to make pretty URL's (it's not wordpress).

```
<meta property="og:title" content="This is a unique shop title"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.com/shops/uniqueshop"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/uploads/uniqueimage.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Interesting general description. Same on all pages"/>
```

The 'like' button code is

```
  <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.mysite.com/shops/uniqueshop&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:21px;margin:0;" allowTransparency="true" class="like social"></iframe>
```

Does Facebook like bypass .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Javascript SDK based like button instead of the iframe based one, this should fix your issues.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Its the (default) HTML5 option when you grab the code from this page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: I integrated the HTML5 and the issue is the same

Comment: It seems i'm incorrect about my suggestion, apparently it should work fine with the iframe, so it must be something else. Have you perhaps missed the [correct html tag](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)? You should also try to run the code through the [facebook debugger.](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this tool

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug